Folder Action Applescript
I'm struggling to create a Folder Action to Open Number Application to run a script and save
Sounds easy but not having done this before its all very confusing
I have a AppleScript which I use currently but this means manually opening each CSV file, selecting the Table then running the Scrip and then Saving the File
I'd love to be able to do this with a Folder action, below is the script I run manually, if one of you clever people can help it would be appreciated.
CURRENT SCRIPT
tell application "Numbers"
activate
try
    if not (exists document 1) then error number 1000
    tell document 1
        try
            tell active sheet
                set the selectedTable to ¬
                    (the first table whose class of selection range is range)
            end tell
        on error
            error number 1001
        end try
        tell selectedTable
            -- currently, use of headers and footers cannot be determined by a script.
            -- make the following assumptions:
            set usesHeaders to true -- assume 1 row and 1 column
            set usesFooters to false -- assume 1 row
            -- add a new column
            add column after last column
            set the summationColumn to the last column
            -- set the formula of each cell of the summation column
            tell summationColumn
                if usesHeaders is true then
                    set startIndex to 2
                else
                    set startIndex to 1
                end if
                repeat with i from startIndex to the count of cells
                    -- get the row of the cell
                    set thisRow to the row of cell i
                    -- determine range coordinates
                    set the rangeStart to the name of cell startIndex of thisRow
                    set the rangeEnd to the name of cell -2 of thisRow
                    -- create formula using SUM function
                    set the summationFormula to ¬
                        ("=CEILING(" & rangeEnd & "," & 16 & ")") as string
                    -- set the formula to the cell
                    set the value of cell i to summationFormula
                end repeat
            end tell
        end tell
        tell selectedTable
            -- currently, use of headers and footers cannot be determined by a script.
            -- make the following assumptions:
            set usesHeaders to true -- assume 1 row and 1 column
            set usesFooters to false -- assume 1 row
            -- add a new column
            add column after last column
            set the summationColumn to the last column
            -- set the formula of each cell of the summation column
            tell summationColumn
                if usesHeaders is true then
                    set startIndex to 2
                else
                    set startIndex to 1
                end if
                repeat with i from startIndex to the count of cells
                    -- get the row of the cell
                    set thisRow to the row of cell i
                    -- determine range coordinates
                    set the rangeStart to the name of cell startIndex of thisRow
                    set the rangeEnd to the name of cell -2 of thisRow
                    -- create formula using SUM function
                    set the summationFormula to ¬
                        ("=SUM(" & rangeEnd & "/" & 16 & ")") as string
                    -- set the formula to the cell
                    set the value of cell i to summationFormula
                end repeat
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
    tell selectedTable
        set Qty2 to "Qty2"
        set Pr1 to "Print"
        set the value of cell 1 of column "J" to Qty2
        set the value of cell 1 of column "K" to Pr1
    end tell
    
on error errorMessage number errorNumber
    if errorNumber is 1000 then
        set alertString to "MISSING RESOURCE"
        set errorMessage to ¬
            "Please create or open a document before running this script."
    else if errorNumber is 1001 then
        set alertString to "SELECTION ERROR"
        set errorMessage to ¬
            "Please select a table before running this script."
    else
        set alertString to "EXECUTION ERROR"
    end if
    if errorNumber is not -128 then
        display alert alertString message errorMessage buttons {"Cancel"}
    end if
    error number -128
end try

end tell
Tried all variants but I'm unable to to selct the Table within Nimbers to run the Script, not even got as far as saving the files
